# "It seem" vs "It seems"

Tags: grammar, bare-infinitive, verb-agreement

Today I came across this [NY Times' article](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/09/22/magazine/no-comments.html?pagewanted=2&_r=1&), where it's written:

> Talking to people at newspapers makes **it seem** as if the future of
>   comments is all social log-ins and filtering algorithms.

But I didn't quite understand why it says "it seem" instead of "it seems".

Can anybody explain it to me?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I've never come across anyone saying "It seem", other than when listening to people speak pidgin.

Comment: @BlessedGeek yet the example given is not pidgin.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question details. I was thinking "it seems". Didn't realise, the question was about something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Seem* here is the infinitive.  *It,* anyway, is an object, not a subject (consider: *her hat makes her seem aloof,* not *makes she seem aloof*).

The infinitive, appearing without the preposition *to,* is called the *bare infinitive.*  A discussion can be found here: http://www.grammaring.com/make-object-bare-infinitive

Comment: Ok, I get it. And this only happens with these structures: **"HAVE, GET, LET, MAKE + object + infinitive"**, meaning _"force someone to do something they do not want to do"_, right?

Comment: @RogérioRodriguesdeAlcântara the meaning is not always "force someone to do something they do not want to do" and there are other verbs that can use this construction.  "Help" comes to mind, for example.